# Moving Files from one folder to another by a specific user from a Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

I am using Sharepoint Online and I created shared folders structure for our departments.

There are 3 folders like Folder1, Folder2, Folder3.

If a user part of group A and has the permission only to Folder1.  but he is not the part Folder2 (while inheriting the permission).

So, my question is, how can move the files from Folder1 to Folder2?

because these 3 folders are under one sub tree structure. so a user from Group A should be able to move any
 file from one Folder1 to Folder2,, BUT not to Folder3.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify a little bit more about the specific sentence?:

"If a user part of group A and has the permission only to Folder1. but he is not the part Folder2 (while inheriting the permission)." 

Apart from that I think you can solve it just with different permissions for Group A on Folder 3. Please clarify us.

Comment: I've a folder named 'Document'.  Under this, I've 3 folders. let's say Folder1, Folder2 and Folder3.  Folder1 has inherited with some permission to a user.  but This particular user not at all the part of Folder2. but my requirement is, he should have the access to copy/move the file to folder1 to folder2. Let's say(Draft state to In approval state).   when he is not in the approval state (folder2) , how can he able to copy the files from draft to in approval state?   Thank you.

Comment: You're saying you need (for that user) to have permission to write to Folder2 but not to read what's on it? (just to make sure I'm following you before any answer)

Comment: yes, the user can copy the files to folder2 from folder1, but should not have the access to folder3 (to copy files.)